# How to return pushed array response in node js after completing the foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, arrays, foreach

I am running one foreach loop and trying to send the data to the client. but when its coming out  from the loop its giving empty array since i have declared variable globally. i want to push the loanid separately and return it as a response  here is my code snippet

```
if (notificationType == "sms" || notificationType == "both") {
  let invalidLoanID = [];
  let text = ""
  notificationPayload.forEach((element) => {
    let checkQuery =
      "select * from loan where loanid = " + "'" + element.loanid + "'";
    sql
      .query(checkQuery)
      .then((loanResponse) => {
        // console.log("------",loanResponse)
        if (loanResponse.length == 0) {
          text = element.loanid
          invalidLoanID.push(text);
          console.log("===", invalidLoanID);
        }
        if (loanResponse.length > 0) {
          let insertQuery =
            "INSERT INTO notification " +
            "(loanid, userid, language, notificationmsg, createddt, expirydt, " +
            "notificationtype, isFailed, failureremarks,isSMSSent) VALUES " +
            "(" + 
            "'" +
            element.loanid +
            "'," +
            "'" +
            element.userid +
            "'," +
            "'" +
            element.langauge +
            "'," +
            "'" +
            "Loan no:"+ element.loanid +"; " + element.notificationMsg +
            "'," +
            "'" +
            element.createdate +
            "'," +
            "'" +
            element.expiryDate +
            "'," +
            "'" +
            element.notificationType +
            "'," +
            +element.isFailed +
            ", '" +
            element.failureremarks +
            "', 0" +")";
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(400).json({
          status: 400,
          message: err,
        });
      });
      }) 
  })
}
```

res.status(200).send({
response: "Success",
message: "Message sent sucessfully",
invalidLoanID : invalidLoanID

Answer (score 0):

Try to use async/await.

Basically, when you work with Promises using .then(), your code doesn't wait your Promise to be resolved. Then, your code is passing before by "res.status(200).send..." and after your Promise is resolved in your .then()

Using async/await you can "force" your code wait this Promise to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
sql
  .query(checkQuery)
  .then((loanResponse) => { 
   ...... **your code** ......
    res.status(200).send({
    response: "Success",
    message: "Message sent sucessfully",
    invalidLoanID : invalidLoanID

  })  }).catch((){})
```

your response code resolve first ,it wont be wait query.***then***()

Comment: i have to return a response after foreach loop. this code is giving an error